# structure of tweet specially - Retweet - Logic of my code

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I doing some analysis on tweets and I got an unexpected answer to my line of code

`all_tweets` is a list of all the tweets in `str` format.
so I used json.loads to get it into dictionary format.

If the tweet has `retweet_status` in it than it is a retweet and it returns the original tweet.

So attribute `retweeted` returns bool on whether the tweet was retweeted or not.

So just for curiosity, I tried to go to a retweet, through that to go to the original tweet, and then to check whether it is retweeted or not.

```
json.loads(all_tweets[4])['retweeted_status']['retweeted']
```

Expected: True

But it returned: False

Answer (score 0):

From the Twitter documentation it appears that the **retweeted** attribute tells only if the tweet was reteweeted by the **auhtenticating user**, so by the user you are calling the API with. In general it will be set to **true** only if the user you are authenticating with retweeted the tweet.

To see if a tweet was retweeted just check for the presence of the **retweeted_status** attribute (that contains the original tweet).

Reference:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html

Comment: So is there any way to check given a tweet, weather it is tweeted again or not?

Comment: As i already answered, just check if the retweeted_status is present, if it is present then it has been retweeted, and that field will also contain the original tweet. Next time be sure to read the documentation and pay attention to the answers you get here.

Comment: I got that, I am not asking whether the tweet is a retweet or not. I am asking given a tweet, is that tweeted again or not. both are different things.

Comment: Explain your question better and give some examples, it will be better if you modify the original question. In any case, when you get the original tweet back, it will never show as a retweet, because it is the original.